# javascript ajax call after an ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

just wanna ask about ajax call after an ajax call. I don't have my code here cause this is not my computer. but, I hope that you can answer my question. I'm having trouble using the `ajax.responseText` on an ajax call after an ajax. So i had this ajax on modal form to add a user and when it succeeded adding user it will call an ajax request to load the new user on table, being dynamic, and after that it will again call an ajax request for a new modal(my own modal), actually it's still a form where in the admin would check the checkboxes to add some roles for the user. I have made a function for that form, so in case the form is submitted it will call that function and inside that function is an ajax request also. So my problem is in here. When I try to alert the `ajax.responseText` it alerts the old `ajax.responseText`. So maybe there is a way to reset those old `responseText` cause I could not override it. Please answer as soon as you read this. Don't worry I'll post my code as soon as I have the time.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.Can you please format your question as a question rather than a story ? Oh , code blocks/samples will be  helpful.

Comment: Try to make your ajax "async:false". This should work with your case.